Окошко с настройками в Unity
В некоторых играх, сделанных на Unity, при запуске можно увидеть подобное окошко (например в Fears To Fathom или в The Forest): 
 
Как сделать такое же окошко? Я облазил весь интернет и не смог найти ответ, может я просто не правильно гуглил, а может ответа нет.

Что-то типа такого? https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/how-to-create-a-settings-menu-in-unity/

Так дело в том, что такие туториалы везде найти можно, но я спрашивал как сделать такое окошко, что-то вроде лаунчера. И если посмотреть на игры, где оно используется, то можно увидеть, что они одинаковые. То есть где-то наверно должна быть какая-то настройка или что-то вроде того, чтобы добавить это окошко.

То что ты показываешь было по умолчанию в старых версиях, этот лаунчер, который раньше появлялся при запуске Unity-приложений, называется "Screen Selector". Начиная с Unity 2019.3, его убрали, для чего то подобного можно написать собственное решение как предлагали выше или поискать энтузиастов которое смогли создать что то похожее на опер соурсе

Ok google: unity3d launcher for game
Практически в верху выпадет ссылка на Make an Awesome Launcher for all your Games! от Code Monkey.
Лончер у него это просто проект на Unity3D в оконном режиме. Можешь сделать окно хоть с помощью Winforms, Xamarin или Maui.

Он использует метод запуска внешнего процесса Process.Start(). В ролике он лишь указывает путь до внешнего приложения, которое нужно запустить, но так-же можно передать и параметры.
Параметры передаются в виде строк. Эти параметры может передавать и сам exe, если их прописать. В интернете можно найти параметры для разных игр, вроде: -w 1920, -h 1080, -fullscreen и т.д.

Параметры передаются в точку входа в приложение.
static void Main (string[] args)
{
   ...
}

У Unity3D эта точка входа разумеется в самом движке, но параметры мы всё равно можем прочесть с помощью метода Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
foreach (string a in args)
    Debug.Log(a);


Во всём этом Unity3D вообще никак не участвует.
Кстати нужно исходить из того, что приложение может быть запущено и не через лорнчер, без параметров. Должны быть какие-то дефолтные значения и сохранение последних применённых значений.
